# How to import huge data and avoid server timeout in PHP?

Tags: php, import

do you have a tip for me on how to import large amounts of data (20,000 contacts for example) into a PHP MySQL table without getting problems with the server timeout? E.g. that the import first imports 100, then another 100 and so on. Does anyone have a keyword I could search for?

Comment: Always use shell scripts for large data migrations.

Comment: Look at [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), load the data into a table without indexes and add the indexes later, consider running the MySQL client from the command line and not using PHP